# How to prevent race conditions with react useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that uses hooks state (useState) api to track the data.

The object looks like this

```
const [data,setData] =  React.useState({})
```

Now I have multiple buttons which make API requests and set the data with the new key

```
setAPIData = (key,APIdata) => {

    const dup = {
      ...data,
      [key]:APIdata
    }
    setData(dup)
}
```

Now if I make multiple requests at the same time , it results in race conditions since setting state in react is asynchronous and I get the previous value.

In class-based components, we can pass an updater function to get the updated value, how to do this hooks based component.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You must use setData with a function as its argument. Then it will always get the previous state, no matter what order it will be called.

```
const [data,setData] =  React.useState({})
```

```
setData(prevData => ({
  ...prevData,
  [key]: APIdata
}));
```

Documentation: somewhat hidden in hook api reference.
[reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: It is only in the hooks referece in the official docs.: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: Here is the relevant section from the new docs site: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state